# How to get the names of the last child directory in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, io, directory

How to get the name of the last folder.
I try something like this:

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("D:\\" + new DateTime(2016, 11, 2).ToString("d-MM-yyyy"))
                           .ToList()
                           .ForEach(a => a.Split('/')[1]);
```

Comment: So what was the output and what is ur expected output ??

Comment: @MohitShrivastava :
List like this:
`rep1
rep2
rep3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.Last`:

```
var fullName = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\").Last();
var folderName = fullName.Substring(fullName.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
```

Or `OrderByDescending`:

```
var fullName = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\")
                        .OrderByDescending(directory => /* some predicate */)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
if(fullName != null)
    var folderName = fullName.Substring(fullName.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
```

*For `.Last` too you can give a predicate*

---

Putting it into your code, use `.Select` instead of `ForEach` and chain the next function:

```
var lastDirectory = Directory
                        .GetDirectories("D:\\" + new DateTime(2016, 11, 2).ToString("d-MM-yyyy"))
                        .Select(directory => directory.Substring(directory.LastIndexOf('\\')+1))
                        .Last();
```

---

To search in all nested directories use a different overload of `GetDirectories` which specifies the `SearchOptions`:

```
Directory.GetDirectories("path", "pattern", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: It's n't one name there are many childs in the same level a i want to get all of names in a list